# Serving local file for a webpage

Tags: browser, proxy

For some time, I can't use jQuery from Google's CDN. For example the StackOverflow website won't work on my PC. Either the Google or my network has blocked it. I'm looking for a way to serve the `.js` file from a local copy (or from Microsoft's CDN) whenever the browser sees that URL. (Kind of like a proxy). I'm using Google Chrome as my primary browser but any other browser will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)'s `Autoresponder` feature. Just added a simple regex and asked it to serve my local copy of jQuery.